# Tkinter crash in python

Tags: python, tkinter

> I was trying to make a stopwatch in python but every time it stops working beacause of overflow, can someone please fix this??

### Code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
cur=time.time()
root = Tk()
def functio():
    while True:
        s = time.time()-cur
        l1 = Label(root,text=s)
        l1.pack()
        l1.destroy()
        time.sleep(0.5)
Button(root,text='Start',command=functio).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop will block tkinter `mainloop` from handling pending events, use `after()` instead.

Also it is better to create the label once outside the function and update it inside the function:

```py
import time
# avoid using wildcard import
import tkinter as tk

cur = time.time()
root = tk.Tk()

def functio():
    # update label text
    l1['text'] = round(time.time()-cur, 4)
    # use after() instead of while loop and time.sleep()
    l1.after(500, functio)

tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=functio).pack()

# create the label first
l1 = tk.Label(root)
l1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that wildcard import is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Flow of execution can never exit your endless while-loop. It will endlessly block the UI, since flow of execution can never return to tkinter's main loop.

You'll want to change your "functio" function to:

```
def functio():
    s = time.time()-cur
    l1 = Label(root,text=s)
    l1.pack()
    l1.destroy()
    root.after(500, functio)
```

That being said, I'm not sure this function makes much sense: You create a widget, and then immediately destroy it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this instead:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def functio():
    global timerStarted
    global cur
    # check if we started the timer already and
    # start it if we didn't
    if not timerStarted:
        cur = time.time()
       timerStarted = True
    s = round(time.time()-cur, 1)
    # config text of the label
   l1.config(text=s)
   # use after() instead of sleep() like Paul already noted
    root.after(500, functio)
timerStarted = False
Button(root, text='Start', command=functio).pack()
l1 = Label(root, text='0')
l1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).